# NW.js run command what does platform refer to?

Tags: node.js, node-webkit

I'm using https://github.com/evshiron/nwjs-builder-phoenix as NW.js documentation suggests.
When I run the "run" command I get this output in cmd:

```
D:\...\node_modules\.bin> run D:\...\NWJS\test_app
Fetching NW.js binary... {
  platform: 'win32',
  arch: 'x64',
  version: '0.46.3',
  flavor: 'sdk' }
Launching NW.js app...
NW.js app exited with 0.
```

And my package.json file contains this:

```
...
"scripts": {
        "dist": "build --tasks win-x86,win-x64,linux-x86,linux-x64,mac-x64 --mirror https://dl.nwjs.io/ .",
        "start": "run --x64 --mirror https://dl.nwjs.io/ ."
},
...
```

So my question is what "platform" refers to? Is that fine or should be win64 instead of win32?
(my pc is win64 btw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`win32` has, for some reason, became a name associated with Windows in general. It makes no sense whatsoever but it's how things are, so you'll often see even 64-bit Windows software referred to with `win32` somewhere in the name. As you can see from the `arch` key, it's using the 64-bit build as it's supposed to.

Comment: It's actually referring to the [Win32 API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/) (or Windows API). It is an unfortunate name, since it causes confusion about 32-bit vs. 64-bit, but it does technically "makes sense".

Answer (score 2):

The `platform` value will be one of those available as `process.platform` in Node.js: [Node.js Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#processplatform)

As @ooa indicated, `win32` simply means Windows (or more specifically, an OS using the [Win32 API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/)). The architecture (32-bit vs 64-bit) is not related.